# Backbone crashing XAMPP

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, xampp

So I am finally giving one of these front end frameworks a try and I figured I would go with backbone.js as it has been around for awhile and has proven production value.

I am doing some testing with it on my localhost (XAMPP). I am just grabbing some data in JSON format and adding to to a collection. As this is the first time I'm doing this I am assuming I am doing something wrong but my code looks like this:

**index.php:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Backbone Testing</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/underscore-min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/backbone-min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"></div><br /><br />
    </body>

    <script src="mv/app.js"></script>

    <script>
        var test = new App();
    </script>
</html>
```

**app.js:**

```
/*
    Model
 */
var App = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "getData.php",
            success: function(data) {
                var jData = JSON.parse(data);

                console.log(jData); // Data coming in is in proper format

                // After commenting out the lines below
                // it doesn't crash

                //var users = new Data;
                //users.reset(jData);
            },
            error: function(xhr) {
                console.log(xhr);
                alert("Error!");
            }
        });
    },

    defaults: {
        SURNAME: "",
        FST_NAME: ""
    }
});

/*
    Collection
 */
var Data = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: App,
});
```

All I am doing is pulling some data from my mock database and attempting to add it to a collection, however when it does get added to the collection via users.reset(jData) I get no JavaScript errors but the webpage just becomes unresponsive and shortly after that my server crashes (XAMPP stops working).

Any help would be appreciated as I have looked at several threads here and various Google searches and can not find out what I am doing wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the reason for the crash was a repeating AJAX call. After adjusting the app.js now looks like:

```
$(function() {
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "getData.php",
            success: function(data) {
                var jData = JSON.parse(data);

                var users = new Data;
                users.set(jData);
            },
            error: function(xhr) {
                console.log(xhr);
                alert("Error!");
            }
        });
});

/*
    Model
 */
var App = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        SURNAME: "",
        FST_NAME: ""
    }
});

/*
    Collection
 */
var Data = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: App,
});
```

Now I just need to figure out how to render a view and I'll be good, but I suppose that's for another post.